# Dynamically split string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am receiving an Australian phone number from the user as a text input. The string will be 10 characters long and begin with 04. I want to split the string as the user is entering it so it turns out like 0411 111 111.

My current solution is `value.toString().replace(/^(04\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})$/, $1 $2 $3)`

This solution splits the string correctly, but only when the user has entered the entire 10 characters. I want it to start splitting after the first 4 characters have been entered ie 0411 1 etc.

Comment: Please add information on the GUI experience you actually want here.  Maybe regex alone is not appropriate.

Comment: A single text input where the user can enter all ten characters. As the user enters the characters the string is split as described above. I actually filled out a form that had this over the weekend. It is killing me that I cannot work out how it is done. Regex is my best guess, but I am always open to other ways to achieve things. The only real constant here is the single input box.

Comment: Then are you saying you want to add spaces to separate the numbers?  I think you will need a listener for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to come up with a bit of a solution. It is not exactly what I was aiming for, but it does the job.

`value.toString()
    .replace(/^(04\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})$/, $1 $2 $3)
    .replace(/[\s-]+$/, "")`

This strips out the white space on each keypress (each time the regex is called) and reformats it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner which will work for your exact use case:

```js
var results = "0411111111".split(/(?=\d{6}$)|(?=\d{3}$)/);
console.log(results);
```

We may split your string on a regex which targets the point after 4 digits and the point after 7 digits.

Comment: Unfortunately this has the same problem as my solution. It requires the entire 10 characters to be entered before it splits them.

What I am after is for it to split the string as the user enters it.

Comment: Then maybe regex isn't appropriate here.  If you want to, e.g. advance to another text box, after the first four numbers are entered, then this is more of a GUI thing than a regex problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like below that checks the length of the currently input mobile number and then applies a different regex depending on the length:

```js
var mobileInput = document.getElementById('mobile');
mobileInput.addEventListener('keyup', foo);

function foo() {
  var unformatted = mobileInput.value;
  var pattern, replacer;
  if (unformatted.length < 5) {
    pattern = /(04\d{2})/;
    replacer = '$1 ';
  } else if (unformatted.length < 9) {
    pattern = /(04\d{2})\s{1}(\d{3})/;
    replacer = '$1 $2 ';
  } else {
    pattern = /^(04\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})$/;
    replacer = '$1 $2 $3';
  }
  var formatted = unformatted.replace(pattern, replacer);
  mobileInput.value = formatted; 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mobile" />
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

1. remove spaces added by before (to recover phone numbers from being splitted)
2. try to match input using a regex
3. combine matches and handle some other situations

code:

```js
document.getElementById("phone").addEventListener("input", function() {
  var matches = this.value.replace(/ /g, "").match(/^(04\d{2})(\d{3})?(\d{3})?(\d*?)$/);
  this.value = matches && matches.length > 2 ?
      matches.slice(1, matches.length - 1).join(" ")
      + (matches[matches.length - 1] || "")
    : this.value;
});
```

```html
<input id="phone" maxlength="12">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like this:

```js
let phone = document.getElementById('phone');

phone.addEventListener('keyup', evt => {
  // get value, removing anything that isn't a number
  let text = phone.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  // turn it into an array
  text = text.split('');
  // create a new array containing each group of digits, separated by spaces
  let out = [...text.slice(0, 4), ' ', ...text.slice(4, 7), ' ', ...text.slice(7, 10)];
  // turn it back into a string, remove any trailing spaces
  phone.value = out.join('').trim();
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="phone">
```